# Conjugate convex functions property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis

$E$ is normed vector space.Let $f\in E^*$ in a bounded linear functional from $E$ to $C$ and fix $x\in E$. We have $$\forall y\in E;\ \ \ \    f(y-x)\leq \frac{1}{2}\|y\|^2-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$$
 And I have proven $f(x)=\|x\|^2$ and $\|x\|\leq \|f\|$. Prove that $\|f\|=\|x\|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x) = \|x\|^2$, for any $y\in E$, one has
$$
f(y) = f(x) + f(y-x) \leq \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|y\|^2 \leq \max\{\|x\|^2, \|y\|^2\}
$$
Hence, for $z \in X$ such that $\|z\| \leq 1$, let $y = \|x\|z$, then $\|y\| \leq \|x\|$, hence
$$
\|x\|f(z) = f(y) \leq \|x\|^2
$$
$$
\Rightarrow f(z) \leq \|x\|
$$
Conclude that $\|f\| \leq \|x\|$, and so you're done.

Comment: Great. Without using Hahn-Banach or such like.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)=\| x \|^2,$ Let $\bar{x}=\frac{x}{\| x\|},$ $E_1 = \{ \lambda \bar{x}: \lambda\in\mathbb{R} \}.$ Then $\|f\|_{E_1} = \| x \|,$ then by Hahn-Banach, $f$ can be extended into $E,$ and $\| f \|=\|f\|_{E_1} =\|x\|.$

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it isn't right. If you extend $f$ then how you can say that it is the first $f$.